# How to group column names and add suffixes to them?

Tags: r

I kindly appreciate if someone could help me with the task described below.

I have R dataframe with the following columns:

```
id
cols_len.max.(1,5]
cols_len.max.(1,55]
cols_width.min.(1,55]
cols_width.min.(2,15]
cols_width.uppen.(1,15]
```

I want to rename these columns to get the following column names:

```
id
cols_len.max_1
cols_len.max_2
cols_width.min_1
cols_width.min_2
cols_width.upper
```

This is my current code:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("\\(.*\\]*-*.","",colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- gsub("\\.","",colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- gsub("-","",colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- gsub("\\_","",colnames(df))
```

But this gives my duplicate column names (`cols_len.max` and `cols_width.min`):

```
id
cols_len.max
cols_len.max
cols_width.min
cols_width.min
cols_width.upper
```

How can I append then with `_N`, where `N` should be assigned as showed above?  I am searching for an automated approach because my real data frame contains hundreds of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to remove the substring at the end and wrrap with `make.unique`

```
v2 <- make.unique(sub("\\.\\(.*", "", v1))
```

Or another option is to use the `sub` output as a  grouping variable and then append the sequence at the end

```
tmp <- sub("\\.\\(.*", "", v1)
t1 <- ave(seq_along(tmp), tmp, FUN = function(x) 
    if(length(x) == 1) "" else seq_along(x))
```

and `paste` it at the end of 'tmp'

```
i1 <- nzchar(t1)
tmp[i1] <-  paste(tmp[i1], t1[i1], sep="_")
tmp
#[1] "id"               "cols_len.max_1"   "cols_len.max_2"   "cols_width.min_1" "cols_width.min_2" "cols_width.upper"
```

#### dat

```
v1 <- c("id", "cols_len.max.(1,5]", "cols_len.max.(1,55]", "cols_width.min.(1,55]", 
"cols_width.min.(2,15]", "cols_width.upper.(1,15]")
```